# Find Child Gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i am working on project right now . And i have a problem.

I hope i can explain you neatly :).
[image]

My problem is .I want to find two objects in the hierarchy..And these objects are children objects.I mean ,i have game objects that controls the game and i have a script inside that controls the game.I want to access two children objects.is there a different way to find child objects with code .

I've tried a few times but I couldn't find any.

By the way, the code I wrote is inside the Gamplay Controller object.

It can be a little confusing.I apologize for this.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. 1. Questions need enough info in the body to be reproducible. See [mre] for more information. Please include screenshots of the inspector with each of the `Score` tagged objects selected. 2.  Relevant code should be included as text, not as an image. This helps future visitors find the question easier and also helps answerers copy code they need to test or edit for their answers. Please include the code in the image as text in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to find the object via code, you can set the references from the inspector (as you note in your image, this solved the issue).  This is the preferred method for gathering the references you need.

If you are instantiating the objects, you have a reference to the gameobject from the instantiate method and can pass that reference along to the appropriate script.

If you really need to find the objects from the scene, you have a couple of options.

FindGameObjectsWithTag  The gameobjects must have the tag assigned for this to work.

FindObjectsOfType  This is my preferred method of finding references from script.  So long as the objects have a script that is specific to those objects.  Ex.  If your Score objects have a Score.cs monobehaviour attached, you simply ask unity for all the references of those monobehaviours.

```
var scoreComponents = FindObjectsOfType<Score>();
```

Comment: Hi hijinxbassist first of all thanks for your return .As you said, I did it through the unity interface. but when I try to find it from the script, I think it doesn't work because the object I want to find is a child object.

Comment: It should not matter that it is a child gameobject.  Did you try the FindObjectsOfType?